# Is LAContext evaluateAccessControl not supported in the simulator?

Tags: ios, swift, touch-id, face-id, localauthentication

When I try calling `evaluateAccessControl` on an `LAContext` in the iOS simulator I get an `LAError` with the `localizedDescription`: "*This call is not supported in Simulator*" (code -1000).

Is `evaulateAccessControl` simply not supported in the simulator?

For reference I created the `SecAccessControl` which I'm evaluating with `kSecAttrAccessibleWhenPasscodeSetThisDeviceOnly` protection and `[.userPresence, .privateKeyUsage]` flags. I'm passing `.useKeySign` as the operation param for `evaluateAccessControl`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have no authoritative source for this, but empirically, the answer to the question is clearly yes. `LAContext.evaluateAccessControl` is not supported in the iOS simulator.